# Laravel fopen() cant create/read file

Tags: php, json, laravel, file, fopen

so I have this Laravel project and I want to export an array to a json file to use it later. My permissions on the storage folder are 777 but when I do

```
$line=[
  'key1'=>'value1',
];
file_put_contents("storage/app/test.json",json_encode($line));
```

I also tried

```
$line=[
  'key1'=>'value1',
];
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/storage/app/test.json",json_encode($line));
```

and in both cases (plus some more) I get this error

```
file_put_contents(storage/app/test.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

EDIT: The folders exist

Comment: Is there a folder `app` in `storage`?

Comment: sure, I also have the file, but  I want it to create the file automatically if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are working with **storage** folder but by default the path takes from **public** that why you need to use   `../`
Try like this

```
$file=fopen('../storage/app/test.json','w');
fwrite($file,json_encode($line));
fclose($file);
```

Comment: It works! It needs these two dots before the path, I think that's because it needs to go up from the "public" folder. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You are welcome as your issue is solved the accept my answer and give me a thumb :)

Comment: Sure! Stackoverflow didn't let me do it, I had to wait some minutes

Comment: @DimitriosStefos since you're using Laravel, you might as well use the Storage facade where you can. Documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem). It's just a wrapper, but you probably wouldn't have run into this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Laravel's helper method base_path():

The base_path function returns the fully qualified path to the project root.

Eg:

```
$fp = fopen(base_path() . 'app/Encryption/PrivateKeys/nginx-selfsigned.key','r');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: Great! Fast and easy! Thanks@

Answer (score 0):

Your directories have to exist before attempting to put files in them, regardless of permissions. I assume that's what is occurring. Likewise your permissions may be set on the `storage` folder, but not the `app` folder.